# Phonegap (Cordova) - some basic questions

Tags: cordova, android-studio, phonegap-build

It's been almost 3 years since I've last used Phonegap. Recently, I wanted to develop an app for Android (in Windows 8 OS) and everything changed. So I have a few specific questions, regarding the Phonegap.

- Firstly, as far as I understand, Phonegap and Cordova are basically
  the same? Phonegap is an instance of Cordova? If that's the case,
  what's the difference in The Command-Line Interface if I use
  `phonegap create ...` or `cordova create ...`? Are there any
  additional features?
- Secondly, since using CLI, I can do basically everything in cmd. Do I
  even need Eclipse or Android Studio? I can emulate the app with
  `cordova emulate android` and build it with `cordova build`. The only
  reason why I should use Android Studio is so that I can use
  `console.log`. Are there any additional perks?
- Thirdly, and speaking of Android Studio, when I imported the project
  in Android Studio, there was no `www` folder... Have I imported the porject incorrectly or is it suppose to be without `www` folder? If so, is it even
  possible to build the application in Android Studio? Or do I always
  have to rebuild it after every change in cmd?

Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your questions :

- Phonegap is built on Apache Cordova. Over time, PhoneGap may contain additional tools because of this they differ in command But they do same thing as of now. Phonegap has addition feature like building the application remotely. For local builds phonegap cli uses cordova cli.
- For building the application CLI is enough. But for development(javascript) you can use eclipse. You can even run it as web application in chrome and check console log or if you have Android 4.4+ device you cannrun the application in device in debug mode and debug from chrome console. For more info check this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
- www folder is created by default when you create a cordova project. This has index.html and other files.

Comment: Is there any special way to run the app on chrome or do you just run the index.html from browser? As for the third question, I have www folder, it just wasn't imported into android studio when I imported the whole project. This seems a bit odd to me...

Comment: @uglycode I have updated the answer regarding console usage. I havnt used android studio for hybrid development so I cant comment on that :(.